ValueError: The layer sequential_1 has never been called and thus has no defined input
I am working on a AI based project wherein I have trained a CNN model and its name is cifar10.h5. I want to pass certain images from this pre-trained model and extract feature vectors of these images from its  penultimate layer.
My code snippet is as under :-
original_model = load_model('/kaggle/input/models/cifar10.h5')
layer_before_softmax_output = original_model.layers[-2].output
layer_before_softmax_model = keras.models.Model(inputs = original_model.input, outputs=layer_before_softmax_output)

I was expecting that layer_before_softmax_model will be my new model with output layer as  penultimate layer of original model. But I am getting the following error:-
ValueError: The layer sequential_1 has never been called and thus has no defined input.


I would assume you'd have to create a new model with all the existing layers up to and including the penultimate one? i.e. outputs=original_model.layers[:,-2] or similar?

If I were doing this in torch I'd return both the softmax output and the feature vectors as a tuple, i.e. https://keras.io/api/models/model/ create a model subclass - I'm not sure if keras supports this though.
